# Can I use lpop/rpop to create a simple queue system with Redis?

Tags: redis, queue, message-queue

I tried several message/job queue systems but they all seem to add unnecessary complexity and I always end up with the queue process dying for no reason and cryptic log messages.

So now I want to make my own queue system using Redis. How would you go about doing this?

From what I have read, Redis is good because it has lpop and rpush methods, and also a pub/sub system that could be used to notify the workers that there are new messages to be consumed. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: In case you don't *have* to create your own, you can check http://blog.thoonk.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  In fact there are a number of package which do exactly this ... including [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html) and [RQ](http://python-rq.org/) for Python and [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) for Ruby and ports of *resque* to Java ([Jesque](https://github.com/gresrun/jesque) and Javascript ([Coffee-resque](https://github.com/technoweenie/coffee-resque)).

There's also [RestMQ](https://github.com/gleicon/restmq) which is implemented in Python, but designed for use with any [ReSTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) system.

There are MANY others.

Note that Redis LISTs are about the simplest possible network queuing system.  However, making things robust over the simple primitives offered by Redis is non-trivial (and may be impossible for some values of "robust" --- at least on the server side).  So many of these libraries for using Redis as a queue add features and protocols intended to minimize the chances of lost messages while ensuring "at-most-once" semantics.  Many of these use the [RPOPLPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) Redis primitive with some other processing on the secondary LIST to handle acknowledgement of completed work and re-dispatch of "lost" units.  (Consider the case where some client as "popped" a work unit off your queue and died before the work results were posted; how do you detect and mitigate for that scenario?)

In some cases people have cooked up elaborate bits of server side (Redis Lua [EVAL](http://redis.io/commands/EVAL)) scripting to handle more reliable queuing. For example implementing something like RPOPLPUSH but replacing the "push" with a [ZADD](http://redis.io/commands/ZADD) (thus adding the item and a timestamp to a "sorted set" representing work that's "in progress").  In such systems the work is completed with a [ZREM](http://redis.io/commands/zrem) and scanned for "lost" work using [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore).

Here are some thoughts on the topic of implementing a robust queuing system by Salvatore Sanfilippo (a.k.a. *antirez*, author of Redis): [Adventures in message queues](http://antirez.com/news/88) where he discusses the considerations and forces which led him to work on [disque](https://github.com/antirez/disque).

I'm sure you'll find some detractors who argue that Redis is a poor substitute for a "real" message bus and queuing system (such as RabbitMQ).  Salvatore says as much in his 'blog entry, and I'd welcome others here to spell out cogent reasons for preferring such systems.

My advice is to start with Redis during your early prototyping; but to keep your use of the system abstracted into some consolidated bit of code.  Celery, among others, actually does this for you. You can start using Celery with a Redis backend and readily replace the backend with RabbitMQ or others with little effect on the bulk of your code.

For a catalog of alternatives, consider perusing: http://queues.io/